# Shortcut for adding new row or column in Powerpoint 2013 table

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, microsoft-powerpoint-2013

With Powerpoint 2010, I used to be able to add a new row in a table with right-clicking on an adjacent row. With Powerpoint 2013, I only found the option to go into the Layout ribbon/button "Insert Below".

I find this extremely long and mentally disruptive (need to click on the table in the right right cell, then look up to the ribbon, point to the Layout ribbon, click then go down with your mouse, look for the "Insert Below" button, point again, click, then click on the home ribbon again). It took me so much mental energy to add a row, that I almost forgot what I wanted to add.

Are there short-cuts for doing this, like a shortcut key?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you right click on the row or column you want to insert before, you see the context menu which has insert and delete options. Selecting the appropriate one of those gives you the columns/rows left/right or above/below. See picture. This at least means you don't have to go to the ribbon.

[image: Context Menu allows row insertion where you clicked]

The only shortcut key for table row insertion I know is <kbd>TAB</kbd>, which adds one row on the end of a table if you happen to be in the last cell of the table.

Comment: Thank you. Strange I never realized this one. The interesting part is that it's docked unless you leave your mouse away; so if you have multiple rows to add, it is easier to repeat.

Comment: You should highlight that part about using tab in the last cell of the table, which is what I needed for my usecase, at least.

Answer (score 7):

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>V</kbd>     =    
insert abo**v**e

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>E</kbd>     =    
insert b**e**low

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>     =    
insert **l**eft

<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd>, <kbd>L</kbd>, <kbd>I</kbd>      =    
insert r**i**ght

Note that the last letter in each shortcut sequence is contained within
the direction word that it refers to.

Comment: Confirmed this also works in Office 365.

Comment: I love your use of bold to indicate how you remember these key combinations. Can I ask how you discovered that these were the case?